# Issues while trying to invoke lambda, from another lambda (ending up Malformed proxy response on APIG)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to invoke lambda B via another lambda A. Call to lambda A is triggered via APIG endpoint. Using curl, a fetch call is done as below:

```
curl "$@" -L --cookie ~/.midway/cookie --cookie-jar ~/.midway/cookie -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -s https://us-west-2.beta.api.ihmsignage.jihmcdo.com/api/getSignInstances
```

Above invokes lambda A which handles the request and calls the main handler. Logic for main handler:

```
const main = (event: any, context: any, lambdaCallback: Function) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(process.env, null, 2));

  if (event.path.startsWith('/getUserInfo')) {
    const alias = event.headers['X-FORWARDED-USER'];
    const userData = JSON.stringify({ alias });
    console.info('UserData: ', userData);
    return sendResponse(200, userData, lambdaCallback);   //This works perfectly fine with api gateway returning proper response
  } else if (event.path.startsWith('/api')) {
    console.info('Invoke lambda initiate');
    invokeLambda(event, context, lambdaCallback);    // This somehow invokes lambda B twice
  } else {
    return sendResponse(404, '{"message": "Resource not found"}', lambdaCallback);
  }
};
```

Also have a wrapper associated as well in order to allow proper response is being sent back to the APIG:

```
export const handler = (event: any, context: any, lambdaCallback: Function) => {
  const wrappedCallback = (error: any, success: any) => {
    success.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = getAllowedOrigin(event);
    success.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = true;
    success.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET,PUT,DELETE,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS';
    success.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] =
  'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Methods,X-PINGOVER';
    success.headers['Vary'] = 'Accept-Encoding, Origin';
    console.info('Logging sucess--', success);
    return lambdaCallback(error, success);
  };

  // Append headers
  return main(event, context, wrappedCallback);
};
```

And finally this is logic of how lambda B should be invoked within lambda A:

```
const invokeLambda = async (event: any, context: any, lambdaCallback: Function) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  if (!process.env.INVOKE_ARN) {
    console.error('Missing environment variable INVOKE_ARN');
    return sendResponse(500, '{"message":"internal server error"}', lambdaCallback);
  }
  const params = {
    FunctionName: process.env.INVOKE_ARN,
    InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
    Payload: JSON.stringify(event),
  };

  event.headers = event.headers || [];
  const username = event.headers['X-FORWARDED-USER'];
  const token = event.headers['X-CLIENT-VERIFY'];
  if (!username || !token) {
    console.log('No username or token was found');
    return sendResponse(401, '{"message":"You shall not pass"}', lambdaCallback);
  }

  try {
    const data = await lambda.invoke(params).promise();
    console.info('Got Request router lambda data: ', data);
    const invocationResponse = data?.Payload;
    console.info('Got invocationResponse: ', invocationResponse);
    return lambdaCallback(null, JSON.parse(invocationResponse as string));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error while running starlet: ', err);
    return sendResponse(500, '{"message":"internal server error"}', lambdaCallback);
  }
};
```

Lambda B:

```
const main = async (event: any = {}) => {
  // Log details
 console.log('Request router lambda invoked');
 console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

 return {
   statusCode: 200,
   body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Hello from RequestRouter Lambda!' }),
   headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   },
   isBase64Encoded: false,
 };
};

export const handler = main;
```

All of above works fine (no error logs from cloudwatch for lambdas), however it seems that Lambda A's handler is invoked, but it doesn't invoke Lambda B's handler ultimately returning a response to APIG which doesn't have proper headers.

Any pointers are highly appreciated!! Thank you :)

Comment: Try to make it simple, B returns data only (not apig format). A also uses `async/await` instead of callback. A gets the data from B, add headers, response.

Answer (score 0):

AWS recommends that you don't orchestrate your lambda functions in the code (one function calling another function).

For that use case, you can use [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/).

You can create a state machine, define API Gateway as the trigger, and pass the result from one Lambda function to the next Lambda function.